# Sqoop export from HIVE to partitioned Oracle database

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop, partition

I have a non partitioned table in Hive which gets populated with 600 000 records using a batch. This batch clears the data from the table before populating it.
I am trying to sqoop export this data to a partitioned oracle table. When exported for the first time, the sqoop export is successful. But when trying to export the data as another partition, I am getting the following error.

What i want to achieve here is, the sqoop export should export the data into different partition.

> Error: java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:233) at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112) at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AvroExportMapper.map(AvroExportMapper.java:46) at

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop export is one to one simple `insert into`. So first pls ensure column name, data types are same/ compatible.
Now, looking at the error, it seems oracle doesn't have the partition you are trying to load from hive.

Please note, oracle doesn't create new partition automatically unless default partition is mentioned. So, add all possible partitions after checking hive and a default partition in oracle. It should resolve the issue.

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD PARTITION tab_part_hr VALUES ('HR');
--default partition
ALTER TABLE tab ADD PARTITION tab_part_hr VALUES NOT IN ('HR', ....); -- mention all values.
```